# cloning a html div element on canvas without using any libraries

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, clonenode

Get a html div element cloned on canvas with clone node. Is there a way to get it done.

Is there any way to get a html element (a div and a paragraph inside the div with height and width of 100px and background color which makes it look like a square) cloned on canvas element. Is it possible/allowed.

Thanks
Latha

Answer (score 0):

The `<canvas>`-element is a primitive drawing facility that allows to create *images*. It's visible content isn't based on a DOM and therefor cannot take another `<div>`-element (or whatsoever) as "content". However, it may be possible to recreate the *appearance* of the `<div>`-element via primitive shapes on the `<canvas>`.

Below is a (halfway) working example. The line-breaks are a bit off, but it should be enough to lead you in the right direction.

```js
// === MAIN PROGRAM ===
function main() {
  const sourceEl = document.querySelector('#source');
  const sourceParagraphEl = sourceEl.querySelector('p');

  const canvasEl = document.querySelector('#surface');
  const ctx = canvasEl.getContext('2d');
  
  const styles = getStyle(sourceEl, [
    'width',
    'height',
    'paddingBlockStart',
    'paddingInlineStart',
    'backgroundColor',
    'color',
    'fontFamily',
    'fontSize',
    'lineHeight'
  ]);
  
  drawElement(ctx, styles, sourceParagraphEl);
}

main();


// === UTILITY FUNCTIONS ===

// type StyleKey = String
// type StyleVal = String | Number
// type StyleDetails = { [StyleKey]: StyleVal }

// drawElement :: (CanvasContext2D, StyleDetails, String) -> CanvasContext2D
function drawElement(ctx, styles, textEl) {
  ctx.fillStyle = styles.backgroundColor;
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, parseFloat(styles.width), parseFloat(styles.height));
  
  ctx.fillStyle = styles.color;
  ctx.font = `${styles.fontSize}/${styles.lineHeight} normal ${styles.fontFamily}`;
  
  const text = getText(textEl, ctx);
  let textX = parseFloat(styles.paddingInlineStart);
  let textY = 2 * parseFloat(styles.paddingBlockStart);
  let textL = parseFloat(styles.lineHeight);
  let i = 0;
  while (i < text.length) {
    let line = text[i].join(' ');
    ctx.fillText(line, textX, textY);
    textY += textL;
    i += 1;
  }
  
  return ctx;
}

// getText :: (HTMLElement, CanvasContext2D) -> [[String]]
function getText(el, ctx) {
  const content = el.textContent.trim().split(/\s+/g);
  const maxWidth = el.offsetWidth;
  const lines = [];
  
  let line = [];
  let lineW = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < content.length; i += 1) {
    let word = content[i];
    let dim = ctx.measureText(word);
    
    if (lineW + dim.width > maxWidth) {
      lines.push(line);
      line = [word];
      lineW = 0;
    } else {
      line.push(word);
      lineW += dim.width;
    }
  }
  
  lines.push(line);
  return lines;
}

// getStyle :: (HTMLElement, [StyleKey]) -> StyleDetails
function getStyle(el, styleKeys) {
  return styleKeys.reduce(
    (acc, key) => {
      let style = el.style[key];
      if (style === '') {
        style = window.getComputedStyle(el)[key];
      }
      return Object.assign(acc, { [key]: style });
    },
    Object.create(null)
  );
}
```

```css
*, *::before, *::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#surface {
  border: 1px dotted black;
}



#source {
  width: 100px;
  height: auto;
  padding: 1rem;
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
  font-size: 1rem;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

#source p {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="surface" width="200" height="200"></canvas>
<div id="source">
  <p>lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an option to do that. Keep in mind that if the div has a more complicated style it will need to be added also to the `data` style. It is fairly short and understandable to work with and keeps the exact look of the `div` element

```js
const myDiv = document.getElementById("myDiv");
const divStyle = window.getComputedStyle(myDiv);
const myCanvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
const myCanvasContext = myCanvas.getContext("2d");

function drawOnCanvas(event) {
  const divWidth = myDiv.clientWidth;
  const divHeight = myDiv.clientHeight;
  const DOMURL = self.URL || self.webkitURL || self;

  const data = `
    <svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='${divWidth}px' height='${divHeight}px'>
      <foreignObject width='100%' height='100%'>
        <div
          xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'
          style='
            font-size: ${divStyle.getPropertyValue("font-size")};
            background-color: ${divStyle.getPropertyValue("background-color")};
            color: ${divStyle.getPropertyValue("color")};
          '
        >${myDiv.innerHTML}</div>
      </foreignObject>
    </svg>
  `

  const img = new Image();
  const svg = new Blob([data], {
    type: "image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8"
  });
  const url = DOMURL.createObjectURL(svg);

  img.addEventListener("load", () => {
    DOMURL.revokeObjectURL(url);
    myCanvasContext.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
  }, false);
  img.src = url;

  myCanvasContext.canvas.width = divWidth;
  myCanvasContext.canvas.height = divHeight;
}
```

```css
#myDiv {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  font-size: 16px;
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
}

#myCanvas {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div id="myDiv">
  Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s
</div>
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="200" height="200"></canvas>
<button onclick="drawOnCanvas(event)">Draw</button>
```